# Whitespaces between words trimmed in ListBox gwt?

Tags: java, gwt

I am using ListBox in a gwt project. ListBox populate multiple record and each record has multiple words. One of the record may have multiple spaces between words. Is there a way to preserve those spaces. I tried with providing css to Listbox with {white-space: pre;} but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to replace each space character by non-breaking spaces: `&nbsp;`. Unfortunately, `ListBox.addItem(String)` will ignore those `&nbsp;`'s.

Here's a workaround using GWT `Element` API:

```
    Element listElement = theListBox.getElement();

    OptionElement optionElement = Document.get().createOptionElement();
    optionElement.setInnerSafeHtml(SafeHtmlUtils.fromTrustedString("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;you should see 3 spaces before this"));

    listElement.appendChild(optionElement);
```

Comment: Had tried replacing space with &nbps; but doesnot work. How can Element help here ?

Comment: ListElement.addItem(String) will only set the text property of the <option> element, whereas element.setInnerSafeHtml(SafeHtml) will modify the innerHTML property of the <option> element.