# Rendering leading/trailing white spaces in GWT ValueTextBox

Tags: gwt

I'm extending the ValueListBox in GWT with a specific type. The constructor requires an implementation of

```
public String render(MyObject object)
```

What I'm trying to return is simply one of the attributes, `object.title`, prepended with a given number of spaces. The problem is these appears to get trimmed and won't show up when the  ListBox item is rendered. &nbps; and HTML doesn't work either.
I found a solution that works on a regular GWT ListBox ([Whitespaces between words trimmed in ListBox gwt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285654/whitespaces-between-words-trimmed-in-listbox-gwt)) but it's not applicable to ValueTextBox. Is there a solution to this problem?

Edit:
Well, right now the objects in the listbox is defined by `setAcceptableValues()`, and they way they're presented by `render()` (code below). The former, tracing it back to the ValueListBox class, puts each value in a map and then calls `getListBox().addItem(renderer.render(value))` By using your solution is can bypass this, but I get an indexoutofrage exception when I try to select the element, because the item hasn't been properly added in the `ValueListBox` class (the private attribute `List<T> values`)

The actual class (with `render(Category object, Appendable appendable`) omitted):

```
public class CategoryListBox extends GraphNotesListBox<Category>{
public CategoryListBox(){
    super(new Renderer<Category>() {

        @Override
        public String render(Category object) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            //nbr of parents determine the indentation
            int size = GraphNotes.getCache().getGraph().getParentChain(object.parent).size(); 
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                sb.append("&nbsp;"); //or sb.append(" ");
            }
            return sb.toString() + object.title;
        }
    });
    setValues(GraphNotes.getCache().getGraph().getAllCategories());
}
```

}

Comment: Browsers always collapse multiple spaces. You can try to figure out a way around it by using non-breaking spaces (`&nbps;`), but this is a hack. What are you trying to achieve? Maybe there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I tried directly from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285654/whitespaces-between-words-trimmed-in-listbox-gwt) shared by you.

Please let me know why its not applicable  to `ValueTextBox` to that I can try to find out the solution.

Hint:

- You can override the `ValueTextBox#getValue()` method.
- You can get all the children added in `ValueTextBox` using `ValueTextBox.getElement().getChildNodes()`

---

```
Element listElement = valueListBox.getElement();

OptionElement optionElement = Document.get().createOptionElement();
optionElement
        .setInnerSafeHtml(SafeHtmlUtils
                .fromTrustedString("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;you should see 3 spaces before this"));

listElement.appendChild(optionElement);
```

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Well, right now the objects in the listbox is defined by `setAcceptableValues()`, and they way they're presented by `render()`. The former, tracing it back to the ValueListBox class, puts each value in a map and then calls `getListBox().addItem(renderer.render(value));`
By using your solution is can bypass this, but I get an indexoutofrage exception when I try to select the element, because the item hasn't been properly added in the ValueListBox class (the private attribute  List<T> values)

Comment: @JonasRosenqvist Please add it into your question as edit section to make it clear for others also.

Comment: OK let me try to analyze it.